# Problems with installing Python os module on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, activepython

I have recently downloaded ActivePython 3.6 and it works just fine, but when I try to install the os module I get following console output:[Command prompt screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5j5G2.png)

Thank you for all your help in advance:)

Comment: Why do you think you need to install that module? It's part of the standard library.

Comment: You're right. My mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html):

> [16.1. os — Miscellaneous operating system interfaces](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html)

OS is one of the libraries listed, so you shouldn't need to download anything.